# Sql Json - Update Json Property within an Array using SQL Server 2017 Express

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2017

i Have this Json:

```
{
"pType": "1",
"pTitle": "A Product",
"pProds": [{
    "formM": 1,
    "sDesc": "A Product",
    "lDesc": "A Product",
    "pColor": "#000000",
    "pSize": "L",
    "postage": "2",
    "quatity": 2,
    "aPrice": "2",
    "rPrice": "2",
    "Discounted": "2",
    "Price": "2",
    "p_Num": "466ff237439a44be9d8fcc4725c28e4c",
    "images": [{
        "mN": 1,
        "idImage": "image1",
        "fileName": "39b06cc1aeb94e0c868d9b4e8174e2d5.jpeg",
        "bytes": "/img/ProdImages/466ff237439a44be9d8fcc4725c28e4c/39b06cc1aeb94e0c868d9b4e8174e2d5.jpeg"
    }]
}, {
    "formM": 0,
    "sDesc": "",
    "lDesc": "",
    "pColor": "",
    "pSize": "0",
    "postage": "0",
    "quatity": 0,
    "aPrice": "0",
    "rPrice": "0",
    "Discounted": "0",
    "Price": "0",
    "p_Num": "b8cf1caa638b48a2a3111b6d78c90b74",
    "images": []
}]
}
```

What i would like to do is update the quatity (miss spelled) value by a given id which is p_Num.

So if i needed to update quatity from 2 to 55 by p_Num equalling '466ff237439a44be9d8fcc4725c28e4c'

How would i achieve this?

Comment: JSON functions are highly vendor-specific. Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: sql server 2017 express